# Kotlin Gradle DSL with buildSrc compilation error

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I try a test project with migrating from Gradle Groovy DSL to Kotlin DSL. I stucked at using `buildSrc`. I have kotlin file `Dependencies.kt` inside `buildSrc`. When using value to set `classpath` of `app` module. It did not regconize.

[image]

Error log here

> org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file
>   '/Users/trongtan/Documents/Shopback/Git/GithubKodein/build.gradle.kts'
>   line: 9 Script compilation error:
>
> Line 9:         classpath(BuildPlugins.androidGradlePlugin)
>                               ^ Unresolved reference: BuildPlugins

Any suggestions is welcome!

Comment: It works for me and the only thing I can find in your tree ist that is diffrent to mine is that you changed "settings.gradle" to "settings.gradle.kts" 
When I tried to get it working I was unable to do it whenever I changed settings.gradle to settings.gradle.kts.
nvm.. I just tried to change it and it worked as well

Comment: Have you tried invalidate and restart?

Comment: I found the reason why. it 's my mistake. `buid.gradle.kts` should be `build.gradle.kts`. :( . It takes my time alot. Thanks @Traendy for suggestion.